# Simulate MouseClick on Background Form

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to simulate a mouseclick on a Form that is minimized, or behind other forms, without giving it the focus and bringing it up in the foremost position?

I've got the code to simulate a mouse click, and it works just fine, but it needs the co-ords of the click and it doesn't accept in input the Form address.

Comment: You should really show some code here. Is it just C#, if so is it Forms or WPF - or is the form in HTML?

Comment: I don't think that code would be of much use ... it's  a WPF, with a main form that can pop up smaller forms that stack over eachother. I need to simulate a click on one of the smaller forms without moving it from the stack

Comment: Knowing it is WPF will help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) API call.

A lot of examples can be found with Google, like [this one](http://www.blizzhackers.cc/viewtopic.php?t=396398).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way, but you can create a wrapper for the `OnMouseClick` function and expose it.

`public void PerformMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnMouseClick(e);
    }`

```
Form frm = new Form();

frm.PerformMouseClick(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, 100, 100, 0));
```